# onClick Function for created button with parameters

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created a button and now I need to create an onClick function for it.
I've found this sollution:

```
btnEasyLvl.Click += new EventHandler(Game);
```

...

```
protected void Game(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
           //some actions 
        }
```

But what if my `Game` function has to accept some parameters (e.g. n,m,k).  So that I'll need to write:

```
btnEasyLvl.Click += new EventHandler(Game(n,m,k));
```

How to rewrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass parameters to Game because it is an event, and those have the predefined parameters object sender and Eventargs e, what you must do is create a method that receives these parameters and call it from the event

```
btnEasyLvl.Click += new EventHandler(Game);

protected void Game(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
      //Here call the method SomeActions
      SomeActions(n, m ,k);
}

private void SomeActions(n, m, k)
{
     //some actions 
}
```